# How I can include this in the bar in the href?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, href

I have this `<li>` element, and the href must be builded more or less like:

```
<li role="menuitem">
      <a href=
        "~/" @siteMapNode3.Attribute("controller").Value + 
        "/" @siteMapNode3.Attribute("action").Value>
      @siteMapNode3.Attribute("title").Value
      </a>
</li>
```

But it gives me an error: "Missing attribute name." where the bar is.
Thaks!

Comment: Did you intentionally omitted all `+` while constructing a string?

Comment: No, but now use Url.Action ands works! thank you very much anyway

Comment: Indeed `Url.Action` is much better choice - consider making it an answer and accepting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
<li role="menuitem">
      <a href="@Url.Action(siteMapNode3.Attribute("action").Value,siteMapNode3.Attribute("controller").Value)">
      @siteMapNode3.Attribute("title").Value
      </a>
</li>
```

The code you have provided will simply echo out the values one after another, and does not attempt to join the strings.  You can also use `@Html.ActionLink` method to generate the entire link.

```
<li role="menuitem">
   @Html.ActionLink(siteMapNode3.Attribute("title").Value, siteMapNode3.Attribute("controller").Value), siteMapNode3.Attribute("action").Value)
</li>
```